# NPM - Browserify "'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'"

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

I am trying to convert a file tensorflow.js file (written in Node.js) with Browserify into plain Javascript. In the file there are two lines

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {MnistData} from './data';
```

When I am exporting this I am getting the error "ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'". How can I solve this error?

Many thanks in advance,
Andi

Comment: Sounds stupid, but the only soultion I could find was to commit everything, rmove the whole project folder except for `.git` and do a `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 31):

**Update 2023: it’s probably easier to switch to esbuild because browserify has been abandoned.**

---

You can use [`esmify`](https://github.com/mattdesl/esmify) to add ES Modules support to browserify:

```bash
browserify index.js -p esmify > bundle.js
```

Refer to the project's readme for more usage info.

Comment: I get the following error when doing this.
 Cannot find module 'esmify' from 'C:\Users\Development\static\main\base\js'. I already followed the instructions on the GitHub website.

Comment: @FearlessFuture esmify must be installed first: `npm install --save-dev esmify`

Comment: Sorry for not being subtle here. But this is just the top lid of a huge can of worms. Even after @ris8_allo_zen0 pointing out that you need to install something prior to using the answer, there seem to be more dependencies lacking. Given this whole "use javascript package" thing is a major use case, this is quite frustrating.

Comment: It’s been 4 years since this answer was posted and a lot has changed since. Nowadays it’s just a terrible idea to use browserify as it’s wildly outdated. I suggest using vite or esbuild or literally anything else that has had any commits in the past year. Browserify is basically abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Browserify takes module exports and basically copy pastes them into your javascript file. This error is simply telling you the syntax of your statements aren't supported by browserify currently (basically, can't do es6+).

So the first thing you want to do is run the file through babel to transpile it down to es2015 or whatever browserify needs to recognize the proper export syntax.

Comment: What it means Browserify does not support es6? I have this simple code in module export `function test() { console.log('teeest'); }` It couldnt be simplier.

Comment: You need to use babel to transpile the code into es5. Just look at babel + browserify recipes on google.